# Writing only one response, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, get

Trying to get get each response to save.
So far it only prints all the responses and saves one.
Please help.
Edit: need help saving all the responses.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report'
resource = []
with open("/PATH/hashes.txt", "r") as f:
    for resource in f:
        print(resource)
        params = {'apikey': 'API KEY HERE', 'resource': resource}
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        response1 = response.json()
        print(response.json())
        with open('data.json', 'w') as J:
            json.dump(response1, J, indent=6)
```

**Updated!! Thanks for all the help!**

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report'
params = {'apikey': 'API KEY HERE'}
resources = []
with open("/PATH/hashes.txt", "r") as f:
    for resource in f:
        print(resource)
        params['resource'] = resource
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        json_data = response.json()['sha256']
        print(json_data)
        resources.append(json_data)

with open('data.json', 'w') as J:
    json.dump(resources, J, indent=6)
J.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: in each iteration of the for loop you overwrite `data.json`

Comment: when using `with` context manager there is no need to close the file. the context manager takes care of it

Comment: Also, if you just want one string (`sha256`) from each response, do you really need the output file to be JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report'
params = {'apikey': 'API KEY HERE'}
resources = []
with open("/PATH/hashes.txt", "r") as f:
    for resource in f:
        print(resource)
        params['resource'] = resource
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        json_data = response.json()
        print(json_data)
        resources.append(json_data)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(resources, f, indent=6)
```

In your original code you overwrite `data.json` in each iteration of the loop.
Append each JSON response to `resources` list (note the plural in the name - in your code you just overwrite the empty list by reusing name `resource` in the for loop). Then dump the list (it will be JSON array) into JSON file .

Comment: ty, that worked the best for what i'm doing!

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration of the loop you overwrite `data.json`. Instead, you could append to it by opening it with the `a` mode ("append") instead of the `w` mode ("write"):

```py
with open('data.json', 'a') as J:
    # Here -------------^
```

Comment: TY! I was overthinking it.

Comment: well, the resulting file will not be valid  JSON. it will be just multiple JSON responses one after another.

Comment: :-( how do you suggest fixing it to be a valid json file?